# Yii2 kartik DatePicker in modal issue

Tags: datepicker, yii2, bootstrap-modal, kartik-v

The kartik's DatePicker is not renders calendar when input clicked if DatePicker positioned in the modal rendered by renderAjax method.

controller:

```
$this->renderAjax('modal');
```

modal.php:

```
<?= DatePicker::widget(['name' => 'test']) ?>
```

Outside of modal DatePicker works fine, but in mode it does not works.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with DatePicker type. Date picker not working only in two cases, if type is not set or if type set as TYPE_INPUT, any else types are works for me...

Answer (score 1):

The property **tabindex** of the **modal** disturb sometimes many libraries. 
Remove it by adding this script to the view you are rendering in the modal.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#id_of_your_modal_window').removeAttr('tabindex');
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately your solution not helped.